# Javascript function not passing parameters after form is submitted (form validation)

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation, parameters

My form validation works fine PRIOR to clicking submit button.

Once Submit button is clicked, java form validation breaks.

It's as if the java onfocusoutfunction (see below) doesn't send the parameters after submit. You can experience the error in the saved pen below:

https://codepen.io/h0ttamale/pen/MWKjrYZ

```js
function validateNameField(inputDivId, errDivId) {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById(inputDivId).value;
  if (inputValue == "") {
    printError(errDivId, "What's your first name?");
    document.getElementById(errDivId).style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()? I don't want to report error if blank until submit (for UX)

  } else {
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    if (regex.test(inputValue) === false) {
      printError(errDivId, "Valid names don't contain spaces"); //function is in formvalidation.js file
    } else {
      printError(errDivId, "");
      nameErr = false;
      document.getElementById(errDivId).style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()?
    }
  }
}

// Validate email address
function validateEmailField(inputDivId, errDivId) {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById(inputDivId).value;

  if (inputValue == "") {
    printError(errDivId, "What's your email?");
    document.getElementById(errDivId).style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()? I don't want to report error if blank until submit (for UX)

  } else {
    // Regular expression for basic email validation
    var regex = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/;
    if (regex.test(inputValue) === false) {
      printError(errDivId, "Valid emails don't contain any typos");
    } else {
      printError(errDivId, "");
      emailErr = false;
      document.getElementById(errDivId).style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()?
    }
  }
}

// JavaScript Document

// Defining a function to display error message
function printError(elemId, hintMsg) {
  document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = hintMsg;
  document.getElementById(elemId).style.display = "block"; //could I use jQuery show()?
}

// Defining a function to validate form 
function validateForm() {

  // Defining error variables with a default value. True means there are errors and form won't be submitted.
  var fnameErr = lnameErr = emailErr = true;

  // Validate fname
  if (typeof document.InviteForm.fname !== "undefined") {
    var fname = document.InviteForm.fname.value;

    if (fname == "") {
      printError("fnameErr", "What's your first name?");
    } else {
      var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
      if (regex.test(fname) === false) {
        printError("fnameErr", "Valid names don't contain spaces");
      } else {
        printError("fnameErr", "");
        fnameErr = false;
        document.getElementById("fnameErr").style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()?
      }
    }
  }
  // Validate fname
  if (typeof document.InviteForm.lname !== "undefined") {
    var lname = document.InviteForm.lname.value;

    if (lname == "") {
      printError("lnameErr", "What's your last name?");
    } else {
      var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
      if (regex.test(lname) === false) {
        printError("lnameErr", "Valid names don't contain spaces");
      } else {
        printError("lnameErr", "");
        lnameErr = false;
        document.getElementById("lnameErr").style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()?

      }
    }
  }

  // Validate email address
  if (typeof document.InviteForm.email !== "undefined") {
    var email = document.InviteForm.email.value;

    if (email == "") {
      printError("emailErr", "What's your email?");
    } else {
      // Regular expression for basic email validation
      var regex = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/;
      if (regex.test(email) === false) {
        printError("emailErr", "Valid emails don't contain any typos");
      } else {
        printError("emailErr", "");
        emailErr = false;
        document.getElementById("emailErr").style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()?
      }
    }
  }

  // Prevent the form from being submitted if there are any errors

  if ((fnameErr || lnameErr || emailErr) == true) {
    return false;
  } else {
    // Creating a string from input data for preview
    var dataPreview = fname + lname + email;

    // Display input data in a dialog box before submitting the form
    alert(dataPreview);
  }
};
```

```css
/* ----------> FORM <---------- */

.inviteformcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 6em);
}

.inviteform {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 50vw;
  grid-column-gap: 2em;
}

.firstname {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.lastname {
  grid-column: 3/5;
}

.inputcontainer {}

.error {
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #f47b22;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #f47b22;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .75em;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  height: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: none;
}

.email {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/5;
}

.submit {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  justify-self: center;
}

.button {
  font-family: futura;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .26em;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #f47b22;
  border-color: #f47b22;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 2em 3em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  place-self: center;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #f48f22;
  border-color: #f48f22;
  border-style: solid;
  border: 0;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=number],
input[type=email] {
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 2em 1em;
  height: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="InviteForm" class="inviteform" method="post">
  <div class="firstname inputcontainer">
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name*" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,}" onfocusout="validateNameField(this.id, fnameErr.id)">
    <div class="error" id="fnameErr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="lastname inputcontainer">
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name*" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,}" onfocusout="validateNameField(this.id, lnameErr.id)">
    <div class="error" id="lnameErr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="email inputcontainer">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}" onfocusout="validateEmailField(this.id, emailErr.id)">
    <div class="error" id="emailErr"></div>
  </div>
  <input class="button submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Get Invited" onsubmit="return false" onClick="return validateForm()">
</form>
```

Enter a space in the name fields, then tab to next cell. Notice the error. You can go back and fix and error goes away. Once Submit has been clicked, this pattern stops! What's even more interesting is that it only stops/breaks for the Last Name and Email fields...

Here's my Firefox console error:

[image: Firefox Console Error]

Comment: Start by NEVER call anything id or name="submit" if you want to submit using script

Comment: Because submitting a form will load a new page.

Comment: @Teemu `onsubmit="return false" onClick="return validateForm()"`

Comment: There is no onsubmit on a button. That is on the form.

Comment: BTW, it's kind of silly to pass `this.id` -- just pass `this` so you don't have to call `getElementById` in the function.

Comment: @mplungjan Yep, the onsubmit doesn't do anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the IDs of the form field to be the same as the name and the error div prefix, then many errors are avoided.

I would pass (this) in the handlers, then I could get the value and ID from that

There is no onsubmit on a button. That is on the form.

I recommend you do the following:

```
document.querySelector("[name=InviteForm]")
  .addEventListener("submit",validateForm)
```

using

```
function validateForm(e) {
    .....  
    if (fnameErr || lnameErr || emailErr) { e.preventDefault() }
}
```

and change the submit to

```
<input class="button submit"  type="submit" value="Get Invited">
```

I added my suggestions here:

```js
function validateNameField(input) {
  const inputId = input.id
  const errDivId = inputId+"Err";
  var inputValue = input.value;
  if (inputValue == "") {
    printError(errDivId, "What's your first name?");
    document.getElementById(errDivId).style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()? I don't want to report error if blank until submit (for UX)

  } else {
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    if (regex.test(inputValue) === false) {
      printError(errDivId, "Valid names don't contain spaces"); //function is in formvalidation.js file
    } else {
      printError(errDivId, "");
      nameErr = false;
      document.getElementById(errDivId).style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()?
    }
  }
}

// Validate email address
function validateEmailField(input) {
  const inputId = input.id
  const errDivId = inputId+"Err";
  var inputValue = input.value;

if (inputValue == "") {
    printError(errDivId, "What's your email?");
    document.getElementById(errDivId).style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()? I don't want to report error if blank until submit (for UX)

  } else {
    // Regular expression for basic email validation
    var regex = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/;
    if (regex.test(inputValue) === false) {
      printError(errDivId, "Valid emails don't contain any typos");
    } else {
      printError(errDivId, "");
      emailErr = false;
      document.getElementById(errDivId).style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()?
    }
  }
}

// JavaScript Document

// Defining a function to display error message
function printError(elemId, hintMsg) {
console.log(elemId)
  document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = hintMsg;
  document.getElementById(elemId).style.display = "block"; //could I use jQuery show()?
}

// Defining a function to validate form 
function validateForm(e) {

  // Defining error variables with a default value. True means there are errors and form won't be submitted.
  var fnameErr = lnameErr = emailErr = true;

  // Validate fname
  if (typeof document.InviteForm.fname !== "undefined") {
    var fname = document.InviteForm.fname.value;

    if (fname == "") {
      printError("fnameErr", "What's your first name?");
    } else {
      var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
      if (regex.test(fname) === false) {
        printError("fnameErr", "Valid names don't contain spaces");
      } else {
        printError("fnameErr", "");
        fnameErr = false;
        document.getElementById("fnameErr").style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()?
      }
    }
  }
  // Validate fname
  if (typeof document.InviteForm.lname !== "undefined") {
    var lname = document.InviteForm.lname.value;

    if (lname == "") {
      printError("lnameErr", "What's your last name?");
    } else {
      var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
      if (regex.test(lname) === false) {
        printError("lnameErr", "Valid names don't contain spaces");
      } else {
        printError("lnameErr", "");
        lnameErr = false;
        document.getElementById("lnameErr").style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()?

      }
    }
  }

  // Validate email address
  if (typeof document.InviteForm.email !== "undefined") {
    var email = document.InviteForm.email.value;

    if (email == "") {
      printError("emailErr", "What's your email?");
    } else {
      // Regular expression for basic email validation
      var regex = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/;
      if (regex.test(email) === false) {
        printError("emailErr", "Valid emails don't contain any typos");
      } else {
        printError("emailErr", "");
        emailErr = false;
        document.getElementById("emailErr").style.display = "none"; //could I use jQuery hide()?
      }
    }
  }

  // Prevent the form from being submitted if there are any errors

  if (fnameErr || lnameErr || emailErr) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
  } else {
    // Creating a string from input data for preview
    var dataPreview = fname + lname + email;

    // Display input data in a dialog box before submitting the form
    alert(dataPreview);
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    document.querySelector("[name=InviteForm]")
      .addEventListener("submit",validateForm)
})
```

```css
/* ----------> FORM <---------- */

.inviteformcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 6em);
}

.inviteform {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 50vw;
  grid-column-gap: 2em;
}

.firstname {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.lastname {
  grid-column: 3/5;
}

.inputcontainer {}

.error {
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #f47b22;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #f47b22;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .75em;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  height: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: none;
}

.email {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/5;
}

.submit {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  justify-self: center;
}

.button {
  font-family: futura;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .26em;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #f47b22;
  border-color: #f47b22;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 2em 3em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  place-self: center;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #f48f22;
  border-color: #f48f22;
  border-style: solid;
  border: 0;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=number],
input[type=email] {
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 2em 1em;
  height: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="InviteForm" class="inviteform" method="post">
  <div class="firstname inputcontainer">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name*" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,}" onfocusout="validateNameField(this)">
    <div class="error" id="fnameErr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="lastname inputcontainer">
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name*" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,}" onfocusout="validateNameField(this)">
    <div class="error" id="lnameErr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="email inputcontainer">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}" onfocusout="validateEmailField(this)">
    <div class="error" id="emailErr"></div>
  </div>
  <input class="button submit" type="submit" value="Get Invited"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. So was the actual issue just naming? I don't think I had a typo anywhere...

Comment: I think it was a combination since I did not get the error until I had clicked submit once. So maybe somewhere an ID was overwritten.

Comment: I liked the const edit -- and the general clean-up tips! thanks!

Comment: Lastly, What is the reason behind adding the event listener vs. "onclick"?

Comment: You can add multiple event listeners and only one onclick

Comment: I added the event listener... You mentioned adding this: function validateForm(e) { ..... if (fnameErr || lnameErr || emailErr) { e.preventDefault() } }. Where do I add this?

Comment: Oops, I’ll get back to you if you do not find it. I’m off the computer

Comment: Ok, please add -- I tried to figure it out... but failed...

Comment: I updated. Your test was not standard either you cannot normally do `if ((a || b || c)==true)` you can in this case just use `if (a || b || c)` because they are Booleans - to for example test if they were blank it would be `if (a==="" || b === "" ...`